# Returning MultipleObjects using get() django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wish to return MultipleObjects but I'm not sure how as I keep getting this error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /clubs/
get() returned more than one Player -- it returned 2!
```

I want it to return a list of all the players that belong to the club but it only returns one (if I remove all the other players from my database but when I add the rest of the team it throws this error) I'm not sure how to make get return multiple objects.

models.py

```
class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    def __str__(self):
        if self.player:
            return self.player.name
        return self.name

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    goals = models.IntegerField()
    club = models.OneToOneField(Club, null=True, related_name='player')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class ClubViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Club.objects.order_by('name')
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer

class PlayerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Player.objects.order_by('name')
    serializer_class = PlayerSerializer
```

serializer.py

```
class ClubSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   player = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
      many=False,
      read_only=True,
      view_name='player-detail'
   )
   class Meta:
      model = Club
      fields = ('url','name', 'abbreviation','player')

class PlayerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Player
      fields = ('url', 'name', 'age', 'goals')
```

Comment: Use [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) instead of get.

Comment: @SteinarLima that's not very helpful in this case -- there is no `get()` in the OPs code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a one to one field from player to club.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    club = models.OneToOneField(Club, null=True, related_name='player')
```

You'll also need to change your club's `__str__` method, because it currently uses `self.player`. I suggest you use the club's name rather than including all the players' names.

```
class Club(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        returns self.name
```

This means that each player belongs to one club, and each club belongs to one player.

It would make more sense to use a foreign key instead. That means each player belongs to one club, but many players can belong to the same club.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, null=True, related_name='players')
```

You'll have to create a migration and run it after making this change.

Then update your serializers to support multiple players.

```
class ClubSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    player = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='player-detail'
    )
    ...
```

Comment: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
I get this error now

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that now I had to change __str__ to get_queryset.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend including the players in the `__str__` method. Using `return self.name` might be a better idea.